# Another Game Theory Problem

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, data-structures, dynamic-programming, game-theory

We have an array of integers of length N(even). A and B play a game where A selects a number followed by B without replacement until the array becomes empty(Both A and B select N/2 elements each). The goal is for A to have a sum (of the N/2 elements A chooses) which is (i) even, (ii) odd. In both cases, B plays against A and both players play optimally. We have to find who wins in (i) and (ii), given the array and N. How to go about solving this? I tried to build a pattern up from small values of N=2,4,6,.. but couldn't deduce anything substantial. Can anyone have a go at it, and explain how to go about solving such kinds of problems?

Comment: Taking mod 2, without loss of generality, the array consists of 0s and 1s, which can be represented by two integers, $N_e$ and $N_o$. Furthermore, we can also say that the state of A and B can be represented as $A = 0$ if A''s sum is even and $A = 1$ when odd. Clearly the same holds for B.

Comment: @PålGD, yes I get the equivalence relation. But how to proceed from this point on?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Comment: As D.W. says, you can solve this with DP. Try to come up with a (bunch of) base case(s) and see if you can make a recursive statement of who wins any given state.

Comment: For example Winner(A, n, m, a, b) = Winner(B, n-1, m, a, b) or Winner(B, n, m-1, !a, b). The "!a" flips a between even and odd, the arguments are (1) whose turn is it, (2) number of even numbers, (3) number of odd numbers, (4) state of A, (5) state of b.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this can be solved by [dynamic programming](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info).   I'm only handling one of the two games, as the other is symmetric.  (They can be solved using mutual recursion.)

Your array can be represented, via modulo 2, as simply the number of odd numbers $n_\text{odd}$ and the number of even numbers $n_\text{even}$.

Similarly, the state of each player can be taken modulo 2, so $\text{state}_A \in \{0,1\}$  and similarly for $\text{state}_B$.

Thus, the problem boils down to determine $\text{Winner}(\text{turn}, n_\text{even}, n_\text{odd}, \text{state}_A, \text{state}_B)$.

Now, clearly $\text{Winner}(\text{turn}, 0, 0, \text{state}_A, \text{state}_B)$ is completely determined by looking at $\text{state}_A$, i.e., $A$ wins if and only if  $\text{state}_A = 1$.

Then we can recurse and find that
$\text{Winner}(\text{turn}, n_\text{even}, n_\text{odd}, \text{state}_A, \text{state}_B)$ is

- $\text{Winner}(! \text{turn}, n_\text{even} - 1, n_\text{odd}, \text{state}_A, \text{state}_B)$
- **or** $\text{Winner}(! \text{turn}, n_\text{even}, n_\text{odd} - 1, \left( \text{state}_A + \left[ \text{it is $A$s turn} \right] \right) \mod 2, \text{state}_B)$

It can be observed that in this case, we don't even use $\text{state}_B$, and can simplify it by removing it.

Using dynamic programming or recursion with memoization this runs in linear time $O\left( \left| \text{array} \right|\right)$.

Comment: Yeah, that works. Thanks!